# How to exclude file path from downloaded file name using PHP ZipArchive

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a zip archive from some files using PHP.

```
$zipname = 'path/to/my/dir/' . uniqid('MyZip', true) . '.zip';
      $zip = new ZipArchive;
      $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
      foreach ($files as $file) {
        $dl_file = file_get_contents($file);
        $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$dl_file);
      }
      $zip->close();
      header('Content-Type: application/zip');
      header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zipname);
      header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
      readfile($zipname);
      unlink($zipname);
```

It creates an archive just fine in the correct location named something to the extent of: MyZip124153.zip

However, the file my browser downloads is named path-to-my-dirMyZip124153.zip.

I'm not sure how I can prevent it from doing this. I'd prefer to not have this filesystem info embedded in these filenames.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it is going to put the path inside a file name , as you are using the path string as filename inside the header.

Change your :

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zipname);
```

to something like :

```
$new_file_name = 'myzipfile.zip';
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $new_file_name);
```